# Range.Formula= in VBA throws a strange error

Tags: vba, excel

This except of VBA code

```
summ = "СУММ(AQ" + Format(first) + ":AX" + Format(last - 1) + ")"
cell = "AQ" + Format(last) + ":AX" + Format(last)
r.range(cell).Formula = "=" + summ
```

should insert a formula, e.g. `=СУММ(DW6:EI18)` into `DW19`.

(`СУММ` is a Russian localized name for `SUM`)

What happens is that correct formula above appears at its proper place but displays a `#NAME` error. If I select the cell, put the cursor on the formula, and press enter, the formula doesn't change but starts working.

How to make the code above work?

Comment: It's not related to your problem, but you should get out of the habit of using "+" for string concatenation. Use "&" instead.

Comment: Sorry for double-posting. The corporate firewall was blocking SO and I didn't know any of my questions was posted. Adminitrators unblocked SO today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set FormulaLocal instead of Formula because you use the Russian functionnames.

`r.range(cell).FormulaLocal = "=" + summ`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, with other function however.

I fix the problem giving the name of all functions in English. I mean, the function O --> Or, the function SI --> IF and so on.

I work in the Spanish version.

I hope my answer be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the FormulaLocal answer from Marg (1st answer) even though OP hasn't marked it.
There is nothing wrong with the formula itself.

Comment: I wasn't signed in, and besides, this isn't a comment, its an answer that correlates with another answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
summ = "=СУММ(AQ" + Format(first) + ":AX" + Format(last - 1) + ")"
cell = "AQ" + Format(last) + ":AX" + Format(last)
r.range(cell).Formula = summ
```

Comment: Nope. Absolutely the same value will be passed to the Formula property in either case.

Comment: I was thinking it may have had something to do with the + in the last line. Maybe VBA was converting erroneously the type instead of merely appending.