# How can I concatenate strings in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This question comes from a comment under [Range.Formula= in VBA throws a strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722745/range-formula-in-vba-throws-a-strange-error).

I wrote that program by trial-and-error so I naturally tried `+` to concatenate strings.

But is `&` more correct than `+` for concatenating strings?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

`&` is *always* evaluated in a string context, while `+` may not concatenate if one of the operands is no string:

```
"1" + "2" => "12"
"1" + 2   => 3
1 + "2"   => 3
"a" + 2   => type mismatch
```

This is simply a subtle source of potential bugs and therefore should be avoided. `&` *always* means "string concatenation", even if its arguments are non-strings:

```
"1" & "2" => "12"
"1" &  2  => "12"
 1  & "2" => "12"
 1  &  2  => "12"
"a" &  2  => "a2"
```

Comment: what about for a 2 digit integer? like `13 & "2"`? would that be `132`?

Comment: @adjit: Yes, it would. By the way, you can easily test that.

Answer (score 5):

The main (very interesting) difference for me is that:
`"string" & Null` -> `"string"`
while
`"string" + Null` -> `Null`

But that's probably more useful in database apps like Access.

Answer (score 2):

There is the concatenate function.  [For example](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1059968.html)

```
=CONCATENATE(E2,"-",F2)
```

But the & operator always concatenates strings.  + often will work, but if there is a number in one of the cells, it won't work as expected.