# I need to insert 2 sets of data separated by a comma into the same cell using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need to insert two sets of data, separated by a comma, into the same cell using a macro. The data is located in a separate sheet of the workbook. I need to pull it into a summary sheet I have created.

The two values that should be concatenated are based on an ID from the summary screen. I'm not sure how to do this in VBA.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines in the Help Center on asking questions on this site. As it stands, your question is "too broad": it doesn't provide enough information to enable a targeted and concise Answer. At the very least, you need to provide the code you've tried and explain HOW it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you need to concatentate. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727699/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-vba

Comment: I'm not sure of any of the sheet names, column names, cells, or anything else but you can adapt this for use: Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = Range("A1") & ", " & Range("B1")

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8F8AE884-2CA8-4F7A-B093-75D702BEA31D).

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!B2,",",Sheet2!A2)
```

In this example, `B2` and `A2` are whatever arbitrary cells your data is in. You can replace `Sheet1!B2`, for instance, with another formula (such as `VLOOKUP`) to take into account your index.

To just test out the `CONCATENATE` function, you can do this:

```
=CONCATENATE("Foo",",","Bar")
```

Which will evaluate to `Foo,Bar` inside that cell. Replace `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` with other formulas to get a more complex result.

(If you provide more information about the structure of your sheets and how the index relates to the data you're looking up, we can provide a more detailed explanation.)