# Two Strings won't concatenate VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a little Excel-Macro with VBA. Now I would like to concat two Strings and save them into a String-Array.

What I got:

```
Dim rowNumberString As String
Dim colIndexString As String
Dim headerArray(1 To colIndexArrayRange) As String

colIndexNumber = 14
colCount = 5
rowNumberString = "12"
addAnotherColumnToArray = True

' Fill the column array with all the month's entries
While addAnotherColumnToArray
    colCount = colCount + 1
    colIndexNumber = colIndexNumber + 1

    If colIndexArray(colCount) = "" Then
        colIndexString = Split(Cells(1, colIndexNumber).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        colIndexArray(colCount) = colIndexString & rowNumberString
    End If

    Debug.Print colCount & "=" & colIndexArray(colCount)

    If (colIndexNumber > 61) Then
        addAnotherColumnToArray = False
    End If
Wend
```

The output:

```
6=O
7=P
8=Q
9=R
10=S
11=T
12=U
' ....
```

So it seems that this line:

```
` colIndexArray(colCount) = colIndexString & rowNumberString`
```

is not concatenating the String the way it should. What did I do wrong? I thought the `&`-Operator would always work for Strings in VBA.

Comment: where and how is `colIndexArray` defined?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727699/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-vba

Comment: It does. There must be something else at work.

Comment: Your code worked for me (I did have to remove your `If... Then Statement`). Why don't you go about this a completely different way? Create a Range, and instead of doing a `Do While...Loop`, just do `For Each Cell In YourRng`? You can then use `Cell.Address`. It appears you are trying to make this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in my comment, you could be going about this in a completely different way.

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but a `For...Next` statement using `Objects`, rather than `Strings` should help you accomplish your task.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng12 As Range, Cell As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set Rng12 = ws.Range("L12:Z12") 'Adjust your range

    For Each Cell In Rng12
        Debug.Print Cell.Address
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Updated answer to show new method using `For...Next` rather than `Do While... Wend`.