# How to pass a parameter to a jquery/javascript function using execScript

Tags: javascript, excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, vba

I have the following code to select the first item in a kendoDropDownList. By changing the parameter in *select* from a 1 to a 2, I can select the second item. Is there a way to pass a parameter, as in 1 or 2 or 3 etc. to this line ?

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "$('#drgdTankCrude').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($('#Tank_ID').data('kendoDropDownList').select(1));"
```

I've tried the following by setting a variable called xp using double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, but nothing happens unless it's actually a number of valid items in the dropDownList.

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "$('#drgdTankCrude').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($('#Tank_ID').data('kendoDropDownList').select(""xp""));"
```

Comment: `select(" & xp & ")` in VBA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727699/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-vba

Comment: @Slai, thank you. That does it ! Now I just need to figure out how to determine the right index number for the number I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slai gave me the correct answer. The line is posted below.

Setting the xp variable, it was passed correctly

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "$('#drgdTankCrude').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($('#Tank_ID').data('kendoDropDownList').select(" & xp & "));"
```