# How can I insert a character into a string? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of product numbers that are all formatted like this:

```
MK444LLA
```

...same number and letter pattern, same character count. I need to insert a `/` into each cell so they all end up like this:

```
MK444LL/A
```

I'm thinking I just need a solution for the first row, which I can then apply to the entire column.

Comment: Why can't `=LEFT(A1,7) & "/" & RIGHT(A1,1)` work?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It can and that's pretty much my answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Left` and `Right` string functions](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/string-manipulation.html) and [concatenate the three parts together with `&`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1727699/3151675).

```
Left(Range("A1").Text, 7) & "/" & Right(Range("A1").Text, 1)
```

`Left(Range("A1").Text, 7)` - this returns the first seven characters.

`Right(Range("A1").Text, 1)` - this returns the last character.

Comment: My resulting string comes out in an odd format. "MK-01-1/34"

Comment: @chlee218 in your question you said all rows had the same character count but the example you mentioned in that comment is a different length than the example from your question....

Comment: @chlee218 if instead each row can have different size then use 
`Left(Range("A1").Text, Len(Range("A1").Text) - 1) & "/" & Right(Range("A1").Text, 1)`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 all of the rows do have the same character count. But, the resulting string comes out in that odd format (and the number after the "/" continues to climb with each row). Could this be because I used a R1C1 formula to arrive at the initial string?

Comment: @chlee218 it must be, because the answer above will only stick the / character in what test already exists.