# What does & do in VBA

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA, I got a question on `&`, What does the two `&` do in this code below, can we delete the last one?

```
Range("H2").Formula = "=COUNTIF(H4:H" & WKB2.Range("F" &     
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row & ",""AMB"")"
```

Some other code has only one `&` but still working. for example:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F5:F" & lastrow1 - 1).Formula = "=IF(C5>0,""CC"",""AMB"")"
```

what is the difference here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel formula and VBA - Exactly where and whether 1 or 2 '&'s depends on your use case.

To concatenate with rest of formula you need &variable& (so 2 &s).

If there is nothing to concatenate at the end, but there is something at the beginning then use &variable.

If there is nothing to concatenate at the beginning but there is something to concatenate at end then use variable&.

If there is nothing to concatenate at beginning or at end, then just use variable.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is one of the two possible operators for string concatenations in VBA.
*(`+` is also possible, [but IMO `&` is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1727709/6884))*

E.g. `"A" & "B"` will result in "AB".

Or, to use one of your examples - let's say `lastrow1 = 5`, so `lastrow1 - 1 = 4`, so this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F5:F" & lastrow1 - 1)
```

...will become:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F5:F4")
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, it is clearly explained what does it do, would you mind to insight on the first code. will the first code still working by deleting the second &?  As per below: Range("H2").Formula = "=COUNTIF(H4:H" & WKB2.Range("F" &     
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ",""AMB"")"

Comment: @Classique What do you mean? Just delete `&`?

Comment: @JohnyL Yep, just delete the second & from the first code, will it still working, and why.

Comment: @Classique Of course, it won't work - there will be error. Didn't you try it? :)

Comment: Deleting will **not** work, because the second `&` is needed to concatenate `",""AMB"")"` with the rest of the string. I don't know Excel formulas, though, so I'm not sure what `COUNTIF` does and what parameters it needs.

Comment: @johnyL, I tried and it didn't work,  but the second code i posted is very similar, which doesn't request the second & to work. so i am confused.

Comment: @Classique You mean `ActiveSheet.Range("F5:F" & lastrow1 - 1)`? And how deleting `&` doesn't cause an error?

Comment: @ChristianSpecht, Thanks so much， I think I got it, correct me if i am wrong, you mean variables in excel formula need to be like &variables& to concatenate with the rest of formula right?

Comment: @JohnyL,I think I have now got it, in VBA code you can concatenate variables by one &, but in excel formula, variable needs to both start and end with &.

Comment: In Excel formula `&` serves as concatenation - you can use it instead of `CONCATENATE` function. For instance, put this into cell: `=1 & 2 & 3`. You'll get `123` string. It will be formatted as string, however it will recognized by Excel as number. If you want it to be a real number, you need following: `=--(1 & 2 & 3)`.