# How to set auto-increment for range of particular rows in VBA?

Tags: excel

I want to generate charts in excel. I try following code in VBA.

```
Sub chrt()
'
' chrt Macro
'

'
Dim i As Integer
i = 3

Do While i < 6
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("STD 8-A").Range("B1:I1,Bi:Ii")
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

In that program I want to use auto-increment for Range("B1:I1,**Bi:Ii**")
in which value of i which in loop and value of i which is in range can be change and auto increment.
What is actual syntax for that.
In above program loop is working but range not work proper working, and therefore program generate empty chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Range` is taking a `String`, using "Bi:Ii" means literally the text "Bi:Ii".

You need to convert `i` (which is an `Integer`)  to a string first and concatenate with the text:

```
...blablabla...).Range("B1:I1, B" & trim(str(i)) & ":I" & trim(str(i)))
```

Comment: `trim` and `str` are superfluous - `&` is enough... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727699/how-can-i-concatenate-strings-in-vba

Comment: @BigBen, thanks for the contribution. I do this because I remember some kind of problem I had with this (maybe using an older version, I really don't rememeber). So I kept this habit.... maybe it's indeed totally unnecessary.

Comment: Not just maybe - it's totally unnecessary :) No need to `Trim` because `i` is just 3, 4, and 5. And `&` is always evaluated in a string context.