# VB6 and MS Access, save time and date if user is true

Tags: ms-access

--

I badly need your help guys. I'm stuck with these problems for a almost a month . I need to get the time and date if the user tap on the scanner.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Adodc1.RecordSource = "select * from tbl_login where user = '" + Text1.text + "'"
Adodc1.Refresh

If Adodc1.Recordset.EOF Then
    MsgBox "Login Failed", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
Else
    Adodc1.RecordSource = "update tbl_login set dte = '" & Label1.Caption & "' set tme '" & Label2.Caption & "' where user = '" + Text1.text + "'"
    MsgBox "Login Successful!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Welcome"
    Text1.text = ""
    Text2.text = ""
End If
End Sub


Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Label1.Caption = Format(Now, "dddd   mmmm dd, yyyy")
Label2.Caption = Format(Now, "hh: mm: ss ampm")
End Sub
```

It shows the Login Successful, but it doesn't record the time and date of the user. 
Help please, help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply insert date and time:

```
Adodc1.RecordSource = "update tbl_login set dte = Date(), tme = Time() where user = '" & Text1.text & "'"
```

Comment: Doesn't work sir. It says:   Adodc1: Syntax error FROM clause; Method 'Refresh' of object 'IAdodc' failed. Help please

Comment: The syntax of the SQL is correct, but it is not a _RecordSource_ but something to _execute_. So change your code from trying to open a recordset to execute a command.

Comment: How do I make that sir?

Comment: There will be dozens of examples if you bing/google for this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest always using the ampersand operator (`&`) for [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1727709/7531598), not the addition operator (`+`).

---

Assuming that your fields `dte` and `tme` are datetime fields, then the reason that your `UPDATE` query fails is because you are not providing the date & time data in an appropriate format required for SQL.

However, rather than using concatenation to insert the data into your `UPDATE` query, I would instead suggest parameterising the query and passing the date, time, and username to the parameters, for example:

```
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "update tbl_login set tbl_login.dte = @dte, tbl_login.tme = @tme where tbl_login.user = @usr")
    .Parameters(0) = Date
    .Parameters(1) = Now
    .Parameters(2) = Text1.Text
    .Execute
End With
```

You can find out more about parameterised queries from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7531598).