# Libreoffice How to convert Cell.CellAddress.Row (is a number already) to an interger?

Tags: vba, basic, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

**I would like to create a String for a CellRange and for that I have a RowNumber, but struggle to append it to a String**
*The 1st two lines of code are only for clarification, that you know which datatype Cell has*

```
CellRange = sheetb.getCellByPosition(nColumn, i)  
Cell = CellRange.findFirst(Descript)




Dim subStrRan As string
subStrRan = "B1:B"
subStrRan = subStrRan + Cell.CellAddress.Row
print subStrRan
```

**When I run it, it tells me that the two datatypes of my concatenation (line 5) are incompatible - is there a way to cast it to the right datatype?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subStrRan = subStrRan & Cell.CellAddress.Row`.

`+` operator should not be used for concatenation. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727699/how-can-i-concatenate-strings-in-vba) for details.

Comment: Alright thanks it is helpful also in my Libre Office. I already know about the vba compatibility, but wasn't quite sure. 
Should I close the question?