# Oracle SQL Looping VBA for number not working

Tags: sql, vba, oracle

So we have a simple query where we we can format the column of 8 digit numbers for the CRN value that works fine, but if place the numbers in an excel sheet and try to get a looping query in VBA to run on them we get no result.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

```
Dim DB_CONNECTION           As ADODB.Connection
Dim DB_RECORDSET            As ADODB.Recordset
Dim CELLADDRESS             As Variant
Dim CRN                     As Variant
Dim ANSWER                  As String
Dim SQL_STRING              As String

Set DB_CONNECTION = New ADODB.Connection
Set DB_RECORDSET = New ADODB.Recordset



DB_CONNECTION.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient18Home1_32bit}; Dbq=XXXXXX; Uid=XXXXX; Pwd=XXXXXX;QTO=F;"

DB_CONNECTION.Open

Sheets("Data").Activate

Range("A6").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

CELLADDRESS = ActiveCell.Address
CRN = ActiveCell.Value

SQL_STRING = ""
SQL_STRING = SQL_STRING + " SELECT CUSTIMA.BCUSTCLS.U##CLASS_CODEC"
SQL_STRING = SQL_STRING + " FROM CUSTIMA.BCUSTCLS"
SQL_STRING = SQL_STRING + " WHERE CUSTIMA.BCUSTCLS.U##CUST_REF = 'CRN'"
SQL_STRING = SQL_STRING + " AND CUSTIMA.BCUSTCLS.U##CLASS_CODEC = 'DO' "

DB_RECORDSET.Open SQL_STRING, DB_CONNECTION

Sheets("Data").Range(CELLADDRESS).Offset(0, 2).CopyFromRecordset DB_RECORDSET

        DB_RECORDSET.Close


        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You are facing the same exact issue as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75622847/1422451) of which I answered with the best practice of SQL parameterization. `CRN` is a VBA variable and will not be recognized in your SQL and hence no result. Either concatenate (`...U##CUST_REF = '" + CRN + "'"`) or avoid quotes with parameterization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub RunQueries()
    Dim DB_CONNECTION As ADODB.Connection, DB_RECORDSET As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim c As Range, SQL_STRING As String
    
    Set DB_CONNECTION = New ADODB.Connection
    Set DB_RECORDSET = New ADODB.Recordset
    DB_CONNECTION.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient18Home1_32bit}; " & _
                                     "Dbq=XXXXXX; Uid=XXXXX; Pwd=XXXXXX;QTO=F;"
    DB_CONNECTION.Open
    
    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A6")
    
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
    
        SQL_STRING = " SELECT CUSTIMA.BCUSTCLS.U##CLASS_CODEC " & _
                     " FROM CUSTIMA.BCUSTCLS " & _
                     " WHERE CUSTIMA.BCUSTCLS.U##CUST_REF = '" & c.Value & "' " & _
                     " AND CUSTIMA.BCUSTCLS.U##CLASS_CODEC = 'DO' "
    
        DB_RECORDSET.Open SQL_STRING, DB_CONNECTION
        If Not DB_RECORDSET.EOF Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = DB_RECORDSET.Fields(0).Value
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "{no match}"
        End If
        
        DB_RECORDSET.Close
        Set c = c.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Just couldn't get my head around why the format for another query worked so well for that but did nothing for this. Very much appreciated and I will probably be stealing this format for everything else like this now :)